# Who's missing in this list?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, literature

My first brother loves the winds and the birds,

My second has been cast out from the family, he is the black sheep,

My third brother loves the waters, even in the deepest caves,

My fourth brother is like the father of Lion,

My fifth brother is kind of gloomy, with his voice as sad as doom,

My sixth brother is named after a wonderful forest,

And my seventh was the last to move and good at wrestling.

---

My first sister is the white, and beautiful,

My second sister is like to a gardener,

My third sister weeps much, and finds much pity for others,

My fourth sister is a sleeper to be sure,

My fifth sister is like the rose in the east(which is related to an Arrow and a Song)

My sixth sister loves the sun,

And my seventh sister is very swift, indeed she could probably run alongside the deer.

**Please fully explain your answer with the few book references I used**

Comment: Any fairy tale references?

Comment: YOU are missing in this list :)

Comment: Greek gods, I'd say

Comment: Great puzzle! I'm loving these fantasy-novel-themed riddles from you and Gracelyn Rioux :-)

Comment: @AJL Those things happen - thanks for the edit.. Great riddle, BTW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer

> Oromë, the Huntsman, the Lord of Forests and the Great Rider.

---

Explaination:

> They are the Valar, gods from Lord of the Rings

---

My first brother loves the winds and the birds,

> Manwë, the Wind-King and the King of the Valar.

My second has been cast out from the family, he is the black sheep,

> Melkor, the Dark Power and most powerful of the Valar. He is not counted as a Vala anymore.

My third brother loves the waters, even in the deepest caves,

> Ulmo, the Sea-King and the Lord of Water.

My fourth brother is like the father of Lion,

> Aulë, the Smith and the Lord of Earth and all that's underneath. Created the Dwarves. Which are like bearded and proud like lions?

My fifth brother is kind of gloomy, with his voice as sad as doom,

> Námo (Mandos), the Doomsman and the Judge of the Dead.

My sixth brother is named after a wonderful forest,

> Irmo (Lórien), Lord and Master of Dreams, Visions, and Desires, and Creator of the Oloré Mallé, or Path of Dreams.

And my seventh was the last to move and good at wrestling.

> Tulkas, the Wrestler, the Champion of Valinor and last of the Valar to come to Arda

---

My first sister is the white, and beautiful,

> Varda, the Star-Queen and the Queen of the Valar.

My second sister is like to a gardener,

> Yavanna, the Fruit-Giver and the Lady of Earth.

My third sister weeps much, and finds much pity for others,

> Nienna, the Weeper and the Lady of Mercy.

My fourth sister is a sleeper to be sure,

> Estë the Gentle, Lady of Healing and Rest, and spouse of Irmo.

My fifth sister is like the rose in the east(which is related to an Arrow and a Song)

> Vairë, the Weaver and spouse of Mandos. Not sure of the link to rose in the east, but the only one left.

My sixth sister loves the sun,

> Vána, the Ever-young and spouse of Orome. Created the fruit on Laurelin which became the sun

And my seventh sister is very swift, indeed she could probably run alongside the deer.

> Nessa, the Dancer and spouse of Tulkas. She is lithe and swift of foot; she loves fast moving creatures such as deer. Her speed is said to have even that of a deer which follow her in the wilds

---

References

> I used lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Valar

Comment: You're following the original question, of course (see my comments there), but otherwise: Sister 5 != Sister 5 ?? Vairë != Vána ?

Comment: The same for the brothers, but both hints so easily fit different Vala...

Comment: Rose in the east is a book reference, and so is the lion, which is wrong(though you got the rose clue's answer right).  If you figure out about the clues, try to explain them.

Comment: The answers themselves are right, but you have no explanation...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to work them out, can't find the links for Aule or Vaire yet...

Comment: Maybe take a look at my profile for some of the books I read, the connections are with them.